# Compiling libogg + libvorbis for iOS

Tags: ios, oggvorbis

I am trying to update an app, but it requires compiling libogg and libvorbis for iOS since the SDK is new and requires a recompilation.

No instructions were included. Does anyone know how to compile these two libraries for iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: any progress on this? could you send me an update: tactoth at gmail dot com

Answer (score 2):

Since libogg and libvorbis don't include any iOS specific build tools this is what I would do:

1. Download both projects.
2. Take a look at the static Mac OS X targets and re-create iOS versions of them.
3. Copy any header files you need plus your new static libraries into your project.

No guarantee this will work but it "should".

Comment: any progress on this? could you send me an update: tactoth at gmail dot com